# Unity C# farming game, problem with lists

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry if this questions seems obvious, I have recently started to use C# and I am trying to create a simple farming game.

I have a "Seed" function that seeds (this works fine).
To create the crops growing I thought that I could create objects with an attribute being when it was seeded and that I could then compare that to the overall time to then change the stage.

To do this, in the "Seed" function, it calls another function ("CreateObjectSeeded") passing the parameters "position" and "timeWhenSeeded"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.igur.com/h0I.png)

I then thought that I could create a class with attributes "TimeInClass" and "PositionInClass", and the function "CreateObjectSeeded" could create an object with these attributes.

Finally, the function "CheckTimeCrops" will compare all the objects' time attribute from the class "CropsPlanted" with the current time and depending on what it was, different stages of the growing process will be called.
(I also passed the position as it will be used to change the stage of the crop)
[enter image description here](https://i.tack.imgur.com/MsFS.png)
The decision of the stages is not yet finished because I keep getting an error, 10000 is simply an arbitrary value to test it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01iF.png)
Could someone help me?
Thank you very much and sorry if the question seems silly.

Ideally, the "CheckTimeCrops" function should check the time attribute of all the objects created from the class "CropsPlanted" and given certain conditions (for example, if currentTime - timeWhenPlanted > 10000, then Stage2) the stages should change.

Comment: Please do not use images of code - hard to read, you cannot copy text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that CropsPlanted is a type (like the error says). You should create a list `List<CropsPlanted> crops = new List<CropsPlanted>()` inside the CropsGrowth class, that keeps a reference to the CropsPlanted objects, and in `CreateObjectSeeded()` after you create the object, you add it to the list, so that in `CheckTimeCrops()` you can foreach the `crops` list and do what you need to do